# Independently scaling the max/min readings of an analog sensor?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, sensor, analog, control

I'm currently working on a project that entails reading an analog signal with an AVR microcontroller and using it to control the brightness of some string LEDs. The signal is generated by a photoresistor whose resistance varies between about 10kΩ when illuminated and 200kΩ when dark, so connecting one end to my 5V power supply and the other to a 10kΩ pulldown resistor gives a signal between about 0 and 2.5V.

---

---

**The Problem**:

What I'd like to do next is scale/offset the signal from the photoresistor to constrain its range to some subinterval of 0 to 2.5V, with the new maximum and minimum controlled by a pair of 10kΩ potentiometers. The end goal is to allow the user both to manually clamp the signal either high or low (regardless of the signal from the photoresistor), or to set the desired range and allow the photoresistor to vary the signal between those reference points.

---

---

Ideally, I'd like a setup where one potentiometer sets the maximum and the other to sets the minimum, making the controls as intuitive as possible, but I'm open to any solution that accomplishes a similar end result. I only have one analog pin to work with, so reading signals from the photoresistor and potentiometers separately and handling everything else inside the microcontroller isn't an option; I'm also aware of multiplexing, but the behavior I'm looking for *seems* simple enough to achieve with an analog solution.

Any tips?

Comment: You cannot squeeze blood out of a turnip, and you can get only one major function out of a transistor. Either gain, filter, or a switch. We cannot help you with such a broad spectrum of issues. Don't beat your head on the wall. Buy what will work, and save your sanity for that.

Comment: Far too long. Remove 90% of the words by concentrating on what the problem is.

Comment: Do you inteed to change the min/max regularly?

Comment: @Sparky256 Are you commenting on the right post? My question neither involves transistors nor relates to a particularly broad set of issues. All I'm asking is whether there's a straightforward way to constrain an analog signal between two adjustable reference points. If this is a less trivial problem than it seems, please help me understand *why* instead of just telling me it's not worth solving with no clarification.

Comment: @awjlogan I'd expect to adjust it at most a couple of times a day—not super often, but often enough that any solution involving disassembling the circuit would be prohibitively inconvenient

Comment: @TheMac. What we are asking is that you strip out the clutter. You say the main issue is `to constrain an analog signal between two adjustable reference points`. Please focus your question based that issue. When we see a wall of text it makes your primary problem almost invisible.

Comment: Okay. Readable enough for you now?